# Values from data store not getting populated in sencha

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch

I have a sencha app which renders a list of users from users json object. I'm using itemTpl to render the users list. Even though I see that the data is fetched successfully I don't see it being populated in the page.

```
Ext.define('App.view.Main', {
    extend :'Ext.Panel',
    xtype : 'main',
    requires:['Ext.dataview.List', 'App.store.UserStore'],
    config : {

        items : [
         {
             xtype:'list',
             itemTpl:'<tpl for=".">\
                                <div>\
                                    {name}\
                                    </div>\
                               </tpl>' , 
            store:'UserStore',
            items:
                   [
                    {
                        xtype:'panel',
                        docked:'top',
                        html:'Please select any below item'
                    }
                ]
         }
       ]     
   }

});
```

Demo : https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/8ob

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the for loop to show the list item since itemTpl runs like a loop. 
So your tpl will be like this :-

```
 itemTpl: [
          '<div>{name}</div>'
          ]
```